# jsp display tags vs jquery data tables

Tags: java, datatable, jsp-tags, datatables, displaytag

I am new to jsp display tags, please let me know which one is preferable whether jsp display tags or jquery data tables. I want to display my data in tabular format with options like search, sort, export and pagination.

Comment: It depends on too many factors, and the two options you mention are not inter-exchangeable. You can actually combine them. JSP is rendered on the server side, and (usually) returns HTML to the browser, whereas jQuery is a Javascript library which adds behaviour to your HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

You should go for  Display Tag  ...
It contain multiple useful functionalities with easy way like sorting , paging ,decorator ,export ,link ,implicit object etc